# Dependency Injection via setter method

Tags: php, dependencies, containers, code-injection, php-di

Have an issue with dependency injection in PHP that I can't seem to find the answer to.  Ok, quick PHP class:

```
<?php

namespace myapp;

use myapp\template;
use myapp\order;

class user {

    private $template;

    public function __construct(template $template) { 
         $this->template = $template;
     }

    public function add_order(order $order) { 
         // do something with $order here
    }

}
```

I'm using the php-di package from http://php-di.org/ although am open to change.  My question is, how do I inject directly into that add_order() function?  Construct injection is simple, and for example:

```
$container = new Di\Container();
$container->make(mapp\user);
```

I want the same type of injection to occur, but while calling the add_order() function directly.  I want something like this:

```
$container = new Di\Container();
$container->make(myapp\user::add_order);
```

Any help?  Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

You can use either:

- [annotations](http://php-di.org/doc/annotations.html#inject)
- [the PHP configuration](http://php-di.org/doc/php-definitions.html#autowired-objects), for example:

```php
return [
    'mapp\user' => DI\autowire()
        ->method('add_order', <put here what you want to inject>),
];
```